# Algorithm to calculate a way between two points in a JPanel in Java Swing

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

First of all, I don't want an algorithm like A*, Dijkstra or something like that, because this algorithms calculate the best and shortest way. I have two points in a JPanel and I have to connect them with a cable that is an array of points. The only directions permitted are up, down, left and right, and **the cable must have the minimum number of direction changes**. This is the most important requirement, and of course the algorithm don't calculate the shortest path. How can I do it? There is an algorithm similar to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you need the minimum number of direction changes, regardeless of the distance traveled, I think the simplest solution is *just one direction change*: If the origin point has coordinates (x0, y0) and the destination point has coordinates (x1, y1), then you only have to travel to the point (x0, y0) to (x1, y0) and then to the point (x1, y1). That is, of course, if there are no obstacles in the way.

Comment: do you have the X and Y for both points?

Comment: @Barranka -- at the most one direction change -- if either X or Y are the same for both points, it's a straight vertical or horizontal line, respectively

Comment: Other way to tacle this, using the Dijkstra algorithm, is to assign "weight" to the points depending on the direction of the cable. E.g.: If your cable comes from left to right to the point (x,y), then you can assign the weight in such a way that (x+1,y) has less weight than (x, y+1).

Comment: You should reconsider if you really need the minimum number of direction changes (which is always either zero or one) or if what you really want is some way to trade off # of direction changes vs total distance

Comment: @pickles given that you can only perform right-angle turns, there's no room for that trade-off (if diagonal directions were allowed, that would leave room for some trade-off)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should look again at conventional shortest path algorithms. The weight associated with an edge need not have anything at all to do with physical distance.

Build a graph that has the potential corners as vertices, an edge for each straight line connection between vertices, and weight one for each edge. The path you want is the "shortest" path through that graph.

Comment: This. A million times this. If each 'leg' has an equal weight as opposed to its x/y length, then any of the pathfinding algorithms again become extremely relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the word "algorithm" too fancy for this simple problem?  The shortest path between `A(X1,Y1) and B(X2,Y2)` goes though either `C(X1,Y2) or D(X2,Y1)`, the distance being the same either way, in case `X1 != X2 && Y1 != Y2` but if either coordinate is the same between the two points, it's a straight line with no break.  The length of the path is `abs(X2-X1)+abs(Y2-Y1)`.

Comment: Even if the problem was that simple (which it isn't), that still qualifies as an algorithm. There's nothing fancy about algorithms, although there are fancy algorithms.

Comment: my understanding was that the problem was to draw a route from A to B by going only parallel to either coordinate, i.e. going at an angle is not allowed.  is that not correct?

Comment: It is, but it has to go around widgets on the screen.

Comment: i don't think he mentions any widgets in the OP